# Ambiguous reference to member 'items(cellIdentifier:celltype:)' using RxSwift and RxRealm

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a CollectionView in a ViewController and I'm trying to get a list of objects from Realm and bind it to the CollectionView using RxSwift.

The problem is that i'm getting the error:

> "Ambiguous reference to member 'items(cellIdentifier:celltype:)'"

in the line:
 .bind(to: collection.rx.items(cellIdentifier ...)

This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import RxRealm
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class MyListViewController: UIViewController {

    var myList: MyList?

    private var collection: UICollectionView?

    {...}

    private func loadMyList() {
        let myList = retrieveMyListFromDb()
        guard
            let list = myList,
            let collection = collection
        else { return }

        let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

        Observable.from(list)
            .bind(
               to: collection.rx.items(
                cellIdentifier: HomeMovieCollectionViewCell.identifier, 
                cellType: HomeMovieCollectionViewCell.self)
             ) { (row, element, cell) in

         }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    private func retrieveMyListFromDb() -> MyList? {
        return RealmManager().objects(MyList.self)?.filter {
            $0.userId == 0
        }.first
    }
```

And this is MyList code:

```
import Foundation
import Realm
import RealmSwift

@objcMembers
class MyList: Object {
    dynamic var userId: Int = 0
    var movies = List<Movie>()

    public override static func primaryKey() -> String? { return "userId" }
}
```

Comment: Your types are wrong. A collection view's `rx.items` function expects an array of items but you are sending it a single "MyList" object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user Daniel T. I realized that the problem was that a collection view's rx.items function expects an array of items or a list, and I was using it with an object. The error that I was getting wasn't descriptive at all of what was going on.

The solution would be

```
 Observable.collection(from: list.movies)
    .bind(to: collection.rx.items(
           cellIdentifier: HomeMovieCollectionViewCell.identifier, 
           cellType: HomeMovieCollectionViewCell.self)
    ) { (row, element, cell) in

    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```